# Repeat javascript function at **:**:00

Tags: javascript

I can run a function every 60 seconds doing this:

```
        Timer: function() {
           setInterval(fxn, 60000)
        },
```

But is there a way to run a function at the turn of every minute? IE at 11:20:00, 11:21:00, etc?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it with `setTimeout()`:

```
function onTheMinute(fn) {
  function ms() {
    var now = new Date();
    return (60 - now.getSeconds()) * 1000;
  }

  function timer() {
    fn();
    setTimeout(timer, ms());
  }
  setTimeout(timer, ms());
}
```

That sets a timeout to happen on the next minute boundary and call a function when that happens. Each time, a new timer is set for the subsequent minute.

It'd make it slightly more accurate to check milliseconds too, but the timer isn't that accurate anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Program the first execution of your timer the next minute turn and then set the interval for every minute.

```
(function () {
    var nextExecution = ((60 - (new Date()).getSeconds()) * 1000),
        fnx = function () {
            document.getElementById("sec").innerHTML = (new Date()).getMinutes();
        };
    setTimeout(function () {
        fnx();
        setInterval(fnx, 60 * 1000);
    }, nextExecution)
}());
```

Comment: Don't. `setInterval` is known to drift, so you should always compute `nextExecution` time.

Comment: @Bergi Really!!?? wtf? No wonder people hate js. Thanks, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

No.

JavaScript is eventbased. The only way would be to execute a timer every second (or even more often) And then execute a function if it is a the right time.

Here is a nice tutorial, its german, but I think the [google translator](http://translate.google.de/translate?sl=de&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=de&ie=UTF-8&u=http://aktuell.de.selfhtml.org/artikel/javascript/timer/&act=url) will help,